# How to dynamically specify s3 path using glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue-workflow

I am writing some files from relational database source to s3 using glue. I would like the s3 path to be in this format bucket_name/database/schema/table/year/month/day format.
I am reading the bucket_name, database, schema, table name from a configuration file. I would like use those parameters read from configuration file to dynamically specify the s3 path where I am saving these source files.
I am writing the source files to s3 using glue dynamic frame.

In the glue script I mention the path dynamically as :
s3_target_path = 's3://' + target_bucket_name + '/' + database + '/' + schema + '/' + table + '/' + year '/' + month '/' + day

Answer (score 0):

Glue's `DynamicFrame` supports writing data with Hive-style partition names (`key-value`). See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions-writing:

> `connection_options = {"path": "$outpath", "partitionKeys": ["type"]},`

This document says that you have to convert to a Spark `DataFrame` if you want to apply an alternate partitioning scheme. I've never done this, but I have used an RDD like so:

1. Use `map()` to add the output key (eg: `xxx/yyy/yyyy/mm/dd`)
2. Use `groupBy()` with that key field
3. Use `forEach()` with a function to write the output files.